# spark fifo scheduling job swap out mechanism

Tags: apache-spark

i have an application that submits multiple jobs in multiple sessions by using sc.newSession(). I am using spark FIFO scheduling. Based on doc and multiple questions on SO i understand that first job will get all the resources on the cluster and if there are some resources left other jobs will be able to get it.

In my spark job there are 5 stages with 500 (stage1), 200(stage2), 1 (stage3), 200(stage4), 1 (stage5) tasks in order. And there are 30 cores in my cluster. I run 5 jobs concurrently on my cluster.

I understand that while my job_1 is executing stage1, 2, 4 it will be utilising whole cluster. When stage5, stage3 is executing only 1 core will be used and other cores can be used by other jobs pending in the cluster.

I am curious to know

1. what happens to a running job's context because previously submitted jobs need more resources. Is the computation stored somewhere?
2. When is the check performed that job should be swapped out or not? does it wait for ongoing jobs/stage to complete before next set of jobs are scheduled?